# Unable to send mail when moved from localhost to live server (on Hostgator)

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

In my local environment on a mamp server I was successfully able to send mails using larvel. However, after moving to production server on Hostgator, I am unable to send mails. I keep getting the following exception:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]
```

I am using my gmail credentials with smtp host as smtp.gmail.com and port as 587.

Update 1: I spoke to Hostgator (based on first comment) and they say that the port is already enabled, however, I still have the same problem.

Can anyone please throw some light as to what can be wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like others have had this problem as well and what it usually boils down to is your hosting company blocking that port.  I would contact them and see if they are blocking it and what it takes to open it.

Comment: And I've found some additional information here directly relating to hostgator.  https://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/technical/commonly-used-port-numbers  Towards the bottom it says a lot of the listed ports are defaulted to closed, but they will open them for you.

Comment: Excellent,  thanks a lot..!..sorry for lack of research..I had found this thing but got carried away in some other research..anyways thanks. .!!

Comment: So, it turns out that I called hostgator and they say that the port is already enabled for Business account. However, I face the same problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they were blocking the port you'd probably get a timeout. "Connection Refused" would be coming from Gmail's end. They may have blocked the Hostgator IP range, specially if it's a shared IP.

Try using Hostgator's own SMTP servers? They're a cPanel host, if I recall, so you should be able to just use localhost to send mail.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you..do you mean using domain based email id instead of Gmail id?

Comment: You already have a domain with hostgator - you can just use `mail.whatever-it-is.com` as your SMTP server to send outgoing mail.

Comment: Great, let me give it a shot in few minutes. .will keep you posted. .Thank you so much..

Comment: Yes, you are right..thanks a lot. However, would still like to see a way around for gmail fixture. Anyways, thanks a ton..!